# Using a proxy for firebase real time db connection

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, proxy

I'm developing android app. I need to connect my app to firebase real time db to get some information and authenticate my user. But, the problem is that I have to connect to firebase through proxy - our company proxy.
I checked some solutions to set proxy such as [this](https://gist.github.com/nighthawk24/9980846). but this solutions will pass webView requests through proxy.

Is there any solution to pass firebase query requests through proxy?
Does anyone have any solution for that?

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many googling and testing different methods, I found that there is no way to use proxy for connecting my app to firebase real time db!
In order to round away this problem I find a solution: Using VPN tunneling connection in app (such as [psiphon-tunnel-core](https://github.com/Psiphon-Labs/psiphon-tunnel-core/tree/master/MobileLibrary/Android/SampleApps/TunneledWebView)) in order to tunnel all app traffic. But, the problem is that it required user approve to make VPN connection.

So, I think we should close this topic. But, if anyone anytime has any suggestion I will appreciate to add in comment.